# AES暗号化処理をC#からC++に変換したい

Tags: c#, c++, encoding, encryption

C#でAES暗号化していた処理をC++でも利用するために変換を試みているのですが、Crypto++ライブラリを使っての実装ができません。
暗号化はできているようなのですが、結果が異なってしまいます。

ブロックサイズとキーサイズの指定が怪しいと考えているのですが、どこが要因かわかる方ご教授願えますでしょうか。

C# Code

```
const string AesIV = @"1234567890123456";
const string AesKey = @"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP";
string strText = "暗号化テスト";

AesCryptoServiceProvider aes = new AesCryptoServiceProvider();
aes.BlockSize = 128;
aes.KeySize = 128;
aes.IV = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AesIV);
aes.Key = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(AesKey);
aes.Mode = CipherMode.CBC;
aes.Padding = PaddingMode.PKCS7;
byte[] byteText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strText);

byte[] encryptText = aes.CreateEncryptor().TransformFinalBlock(byteText, 0, byteText.Length);
```

C++ Code (Crypto++利用)

```
std::string strKey("1234567890123456");
std::string strIV("ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP");
std::string strText = "暗号化テスト";

std::string stEncryptText;

CryptoPP::AES::Encryption aesEncryption((CryptoPP::byte*)strKey.c_str(), CryptoPP::AES::DEFAULT_KEYLENGTH);
CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption(aesEncryption, (CryptoPP::byte*)strIV.c_str());

CryptoPP::StreamTransformationFilter stfEncryptor(cbcEncryption, new CryptoPP::StringSink(stEncryptText), CryptoPP::BlockPaddingSchemeDef::PKCS_PADDING);
stfEncryptor.Put(reinterpret_cast<const unsigned char*>(strText.c_str()), strText.length());
stfEncryptor.MessageEnd();
```

Comment: 環境やコンパイルオプション次第でstrTextの文字列リテラルのエンコーディングがUTF-8以外になっている可能性もありますがOSやコンパイラやソースコードのエンコーディングはどうなっていますか？

Comment: OS：Windows7 64bit
コンパイラ：Visual Studio2013
ソースコードのエンコーディング：Shift_jis
となっていました。
C++での開発経験がほぼないので申し訳ありませんが、エンコーディングが影響しますか？

Comment: AESの処理自体は言語に関係なくバイト列→バイト列の変換なので、入力バイト列が違うと当然出力は変わります。C#側でも`byte[] byteText = Encoding.GetEncoding(932).GetString(strText)`とした場合、結果が変わると思います。

Comment: 回答が遅くなり申し訳ありませんが、ソースコードのエンコーディングをUTF-8（プロパティのC++コマンドラインで指定）にしてみましたが変わらずでした。
C#側でも変更したら確かに変わりましたね。

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> ```
> // C#
> byte[] byteText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strText);
>
> // C++
> std::string strText = "暗号化テスト";
> ```

C#は見ての通りUTF-8エンコーディングのバイト列となります。Visual StudioのC++とのことですが、こちらはコントロールパネルの「Unicode 対応ではないプログラムの言語」の設定値で日本語環境ではShift_JISエンコーディングとなります。このため、入力バイト列がそもそも異なります。

UTF-8で一致させるには[UTF-8文字列リテラル](https://cpprefjp.github.io/lang/cpp11/utf8_string_literals.html)が簡単ですがお使いのVisual Studio 2013では未対応です。Visual Studio 2015以降を使用されるか、[wctomb](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/cpp/c-runtime-library/reference/wctomb-wctomb-l?view=vs-2019)等で変換することになります。

```
// C#
byte[] byteText = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(strText);
// C++
std::string strText = u8"暗号化テスト";
```

「Unicode 対応ではないプログラムの言語」で一致させるには[Encoding.Default](https://docs.microsoft.com/ja-jp/dotnet/api/system.text.encoding.default?view=netframework-4.8)を使用します。

```
// C#
byte[] byteText = Encoding.Default.GetBytes(strText);
// C++
std::string strText = "暗号化テスト";
```

---

> ソースコードのエンコーディングをUTF-8（プロパティのC++コマンドラインで指定）にしてみましたが変わらずでした。

補足しますと、Visual C++ではソースコードを解釈し一旦Unicodeに変換しています。その上で、指定されたエンコーディングのバイト列に変換してコード生成しています。そのため、ソースコードがUTF-8エンコーディングであっても `""` 文字列は**コンパイル環境**の「Unicode 対応ではないプログラムの言語」に沿ったバイト列（すなわち日本語環境においてはShift_JIS）となります。

一方、C#の`Encoding.Default`は**実行環境**の「Unicode 対応ではないプログラムの言語」に沿ったバイト列となります。同じ設定でも参照するタイミングが異なる点には気を付ける必要があります。

Comment: Visual Studio C++はコントロールパネルの設定に引きずられるのですね。
u8も気づいてはいたのですが、2015以降で使えるのですね！別途Visual Studio2017の環境があるので、そちらで試してみます。
回答ありがとうございました。

Comment: @Financier まずは入力データを一致させ、同じ結果が得られるか確認してください。可能であれば結果をコメントで共有してください。

Comment: ひとまず、Shift_jisで文字列ではなくバイト配列を利用した形式では結果が一致しました！
しかし、文字列で進めるとbase64エンコードした際に僅かに一致しません。何が原因でしょうか・・・。C#のencodeは全てDefaultを利用しています。
C# : WQV7iI3fd5s0DKNwSIFA6YkJ30i6/pwUbqYrDrH9q58=
 , C++ : WQV7iI3fd5s0DKNwSIFA6YkJ30i6/pwUbqYrDg==

Comment: @Financier 元質問文にBase64処理は含まれていません。本質問の範囲は解決済みとし、新たにBase64に関する質問を立てられてはどうでしょうか。

Comment: @sayurin 失礼しました。解決済みとさせていただきます。

Answer (score 0):

コメントでの指摘の通り、平文データに相違があることが考えられます。

さらに、鍵とIVに文字列を使っているのが2つの点でまずいです。

## セキュリティ的に問題

安全に暗号を運用するには、鍵やIVは乱数かパスワードをPBKDF2のような鍵導出関数に通して取り出した値を使わなければなりません。その点で、文字列を使っているサンプルコードは参考にしないほうがよいです。

## バイト表現に変換するときに意図しない変換が混入する

例えば`c_str()`で変換すると、末尾に`\0`が含まれるとか、逆に元のデータに`\0`が含まれているとそこで文字列が千切れるということが起きます。

> CryptoPP::CBC_Mode_ExternalCipher::Encryption cbcEncryption(aesEncryption, (CryptoPP::byte*)strIV.c_str());

このコードで渡しているのは、`"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP"`ではなく`"ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOP**\0**"`(へのポインタ)ですが、きちんと理解されてますか。内部的にはIVの長さ分しか参照しないでしょうからこれ自体が直接問題を引き起こすことはない気がしますが、バグの種ではあります。

動作を理解する段階であれば、平文も含めて文字列ではなくバイト配列を用いて検証するのがよいでしょう。それであれば平文のエンコードの違いで引っかかることもありません。

Comment: 元々構成プロパティの全般→文字セットで「Unicode文字セットを使用する」でUnicodeになると思っていたのが間違いのようです。
鍵とIVは一応こちらの載せるようにサンプル文字列です。通常は乱数を利用しております。
バイト変換については\0など理解していませんでした。変換後のバイト配列の中身をチェックして、どうなっているのか確認します。
おっしゃる通りで文字列ではなくバイト配列で正しく動作するようになる検証してみます。
回答ありがとうございました。